VSTO Outlook Addin Get Filename from .msg File
An .msg file from anywhere in the file system is opened in Outlook. How can you determine the complete file name in a VSTO add-in?
Is there perhaps a special property that can be accessed via PropertyAccessor?
I'm desperate.
I've searched all sorts of things with the great OutlookSpy tool, but to no avail.

No, once a message is opened, there is no trace that it came from the file system. More than that, Outlooks does not use the original IMessage object returned from OpenIMsgOnIStg, but rather creates a temporary message in the Outlook default message store; that's the message the user interacts with.

In this specific case it is a message that was not sent. If I change something in the body and simply save the message, even via code, the change is made in the MSG file. Outlook must therefore know the full file name.

Internally, that very well might be the case, but there is no way to access that information externally. You can see what information is exposed on the MAPI level if you use OutlookSpy (I am its author) and click IMessage button on the inspector when Outlook shows the contents of the MSG file.

Hello Dimitri, I bought your wonderful tool a long time ago, have already had a lot of success, I was also surprised about a lot of things (not about the tool) and I searched with it and unfortunately didn't find anything :-(
I was hoping to find out about a lateral thinker's tip or some kind of property. If necessary, via the Outlook application which items are open....

If there is a way, I'd love to learn about it. But I don't think there is...

MSG file, for example (C:\something\message.msg) is opened with a double click, the event handler starts successfully
    private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Inspector inspector)
    {
        if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem)
        {
            MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;

           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mailItem.FileName_xyz_Propety); // <<-- Unfortunately that or something similar doesn't work

            mailItem.Subject += " " + DateTime.Now; // Change Subject for Test
            mailItem.Save(); // File with change in subject successfully written back to the file system.
        }

